# WCF function and parameter based authorization

Tags: c#, wcf, authorization

I hosted my  WCF service in a windows service. In which, I achieved authorization as a pre-filter module with the help of IParameterInspector and IOperationBehavior. So that all function call reaches the beforecall() and get authorized before the actual function execution.

I evaluate operations by checking permission against the user for both the function and also the incoming list of data(parameter) comes for processing.

I have a problem now, from the list of incoming data few may satisfy the rules and others not. Is there a possibility to filter the unauthorized data and send the rest of data to the function call.

How normally this case is handled when using Iparameterinspector. I'm not sure how this type of problem is handled..

Any help on this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You could implement IMessageInspector to alter the contents of the message based on roles/authorization.  However, I think you're setting yourself up for a potential maintenance nightmare.  You might be better served to refactor your service so that the data returned is applicable to the authorization level of the client.

Comment: Thanks Tim for directing me to IMessageInspector. I have already made authorization as a seperate module, I could not understand refactoring here. Can you explain me about maintenance issue, which you mentioned.  Thanks for the kind help.

Comment: What is the format of your data? XML? C# objects?

Comment: That's c# primitive datatypes and C# objects, which comes in as a parameter.